# mysql, alter column remove primary key and auto incremement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1075

I'm changing my mysql db table from an id (auto) to a uid.

```
ALTER TABLE companies DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE companies ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`);
```

This is the error I get..

```
[SQL] ALTER TABLE companies DROP PRIMARY KEY;
[Err] 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Which I understand, I need to change the id to a non-autoincrement because I drop it as the primary key.? What is the syntax to change a column to remove primary key and auto increment?

```
ALTER TABLE companies change id id ?????????? int(11)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you need to remove the auto-increment and the primary key from the `id` column in a single SQL statement, this should do:

```
ALTER TABLE companies DROP PRIMARY KEY, CHANGE id id int(11);
```

In fact, you should be able to do everything in a single `ALTER TABLE` query:

```
ALTER TABLE companies
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
CHANGE id id int(11),
ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid);
```

Comment: If I do it as 3 statements it will work..

ALTER TABLE companies change id id int(11);
ALTER TABLE companies DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE companies ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid);

Comment: In my situation, I only want to drop the auto-increment. I tried this: `ALTER TABLE myTable CHANGE _id _id INT(12)` but it says "syntax error near CHANGE". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

When you're not changing the name of the column you can use `MODIFY`:

```
ALTER TABLE `companies` MODIFY `id` int(11), 
                           DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
                   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`);
```

By doing this all in one alter statement it's also treated as atomic, so there's no chance of inconsistency between queries (unlike running multiple statement in row).

Comment: Best way to do, other answers suggest using `CHANGE` which is unnecessary as column name remains same, `MODIFY` is the correct choice here.

Answer (score 5):

The query for remove auto increment is:

```
alter table companies DROP PRIMARY KEY,
change id id int(11) NOT NULL
```

Now you can see structure of table  is without auto increment.

If you want to add primary key another column, then use this query

```
alter table companies add PRIMARY KEY(uuid)
```

If you want to drop auto increment,primary key and add primary key to new column in same query, then use this query

```
alter table comapnies DROP PRIMARY KEY,
   change id id int(11) NOT NULL,
   add PRIMARY KEY(uuid)
```

Comment: This will change your primary key to the type INT(11) NOT NULL if it was not already that exact data type and size.

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax to change a column to remove the primary key and auto_increment

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY,
CHANGE old_key_name new_key_name new_column_datatype
```

In your case this is the answer:

```
ALTER TABLE companies DROP PRIMARY KEY, CHANGE ID UID;
```

If we want to drop a primary key, also we need to drop the auto_increment from that primary key, both at the same time using the next syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY,
MODIFY primary_column_name datatype
```

there is no need to use the change command because change is used to change the name and datatype of a column so instead of change we can use modify to change only the datatype of a column like in the previous case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a foreign key column, you need to delete the constraint first. This is how I did to remove the auto increment:

```
ALTER TABLE portal_user_privileges DROP FOREIGN KEY FK__privileges; 

alter table privileges DROP PRIMARY KEY;

alter table privileges add PRIMARY KEY(id);

ALTER TABLE portal_user_privileges ADD CONSTRAINT FK__privileges FOREIGN KEY (privileges_id) REFERENCES privileges(id)  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```