# Need help in updating primary key field

Tags: sql

```
create table school_student(
    id int not null,
    name varchar(20),
    DOB Date,
    Address varchar(50),
    phone_no int,
    primary key(id)
);
```

need to update the primary key column to auto increment in sql

```
alter table school_student alter column  id int not null identity(5,1) primary key
```

i am getting below error,

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes i am using Microsoft SQL server management studio

Comment: Already inserted 4 records in that table , after that i am trying to set the auto increment key here  so used identity(5,1)

Comment: I think you'd need to drop the field and recreate it

Comment: ok will try that , need to drop foreign key also ?

Comment: Thanks cid :) for your suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mayur Sawant for your reply from other post :) Its helped to drop the primary and foreign key .

Reference to his post :
[Usage of Alter command to drop Primary key and Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162595/usage-of-alter-command-to-drop-primary-key-and-foreign-key)

First of all you need to find the constraint name related to the Primary and Foreign keys. Then you need to use these constraint names while dropping the keys.

```
select *
from
information_schema.key_column_usage
where
table_name = 'my_table'
From the above query you will be able to find the constraint names.
```

Now use the below syntax to drop the keys.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT constraint name
```